# Torque of a dynamically unbalanced rigid body

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Suppose that a rigid body is rotating in free space, following conditions below.

> 1. The axis passes through the center of mass.
> 2. The axis is not a principal axis.
> 3. No friction between the body and the axis.

Then, the body is statically balanced, but dynamically unbalanced.

The angular momentum is rotating and for that to be possible, there is torque.

If then, where does torque come from?

Comment: How do you say that angular momentum is rotating? Try to write the equation of motion for rotation w.r.t. the center of mass. This reads $d \mathbf{\Gamma} / dt  = \mathbf{M} =\mathbf{0}$ if no active or reactive moments (if the body is freely rotating in space) and thus $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ is constant

Comment: $d\mathbf{L}/dt=(d\mathbf{I}/dt)\cdot\mathbf{ω}+\mathbf{I}\cdot(d\mathbf{ω}/dt)$

Although $d\mathbf{ω}/dt=0$, as the body rotates, so does $\mathbf{I}$.

Then $d\mathbf{I}/dt\neq0$ and $d\mathbf{L}/dt=(d\mathbf{I}/dt)\cdot\mathbf{ω}\neq 0$

Comment: The equation of motion holds, if we believe in classical mechanics. If the body is freely rotating in space, without any constraint that can introduce any (re)action on it, $d \mathbf{\Gamma}_G / dt = d(\mathbb{I} \cdot \mathbf{\omega} ) /dt = 0$. On the other hand, there is no physical principle telling you that $d \mathbf{\omega} /dt = 0$. In order to get such a condition with an unbalanced rotor, it's likely that you need some constraints (hinges) to hold the rotation axis fixed, introducing the reactions needed. Let me know if it's clear now

Comment: As you say, if the body is dynamically unbalanced, is there torque transfer from the rotation axis to the body? But it's still a quetions. On dynamic unbalance, the direction of $\mathbf{\mathbf{\Gamma}}$, $\mathbf{ω}$ and the principal axis are all different. However, when the motor is suddenly removed and the torque transfer is interrupted, what happens? Is $\mathbf{\mathbf{\Gamma}}$ not changed? But on dynamic balance,  the direction of $\mathbf{\mathbf{\Gamma}}$, $\mathbf{ω}$ and the principal axis are all same.

Comment: The frictionless axis can provide torque, as long as no torque is needed along the axis itself. But actually indeed no torque is needed along the axis. Since as I understand it is assumed that $d\vec{\omega}/dt=0$, one has for the torque $\vec{\tau}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}$. Apparently this is perpendicular to $\vec{\omega}$ so perpendicular to the axis. (As I understand $\vec{\omega}$ is along the axis.) So in other words, no torque is needed along the axis. Hope this helps.

Comment: @XXX if you think about a motor, and maybe a structural support to the rotor, you're not thinking at body that freely rotates in space. If the body is constrained, its evolution depends on the constraints. Two examples 1. cylindrical hinge: the body keeps rotating at constant velocity around the axis of rotation, because the hinge introduces the required reactions; 2. Rotor with a spherical hinge at the center of gravity: these are the so called Poinsot motions. In general, the angular momentum is constant, while both the angular velocity and the inertia tensor are not.

Comment: Usually Poinsot motions are studied by means of Euler equations, i.e. equation of motions for the rotation of a rigid body, written in a Cartesian reference frame moving with the solid body (material reference frame), in which the components of the inertia tensor are constant